# Trying to get a specific value from my JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to retrieve the error `message` from my JSON object using jQuery. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

My JSON looks like this:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"invalidParameter",
            "message":"Invalid value 'asdfcom.com'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'http(s)?://.*'",
            "locationType":"parameter",
            "location":"url"
         }
      ],
      "code":400,
      "message":"Invalid value 'asdfcom.com'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'http(s)?://.*'"
   }
}
```

And my Javascript looks like this:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    $("#mobileResults").css("color", "red");
    $("#mobileResults").text(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(xhr.responseText)
    $('.fa-spinner').hide();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read the JSON or how to get the JSON to appear as part of the jQuery error?

Comment: How to read the JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); //your object;
var message = jsonObj.error.errors[0].message; //  Values must match the following regular expression:
var outsideMes = jsonObj.error.message; // Values must match the following regular expression:
```

You can try with this snippet, it works properly

```js
var obj = {
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "invalidParameter",
      "message": "Invalid value 'asdfcom.com'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'http(s)?://.*'",
      "locationType": "parameter",
      "location": "url"
    }],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value 'asdfcom.com'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'http(s)?://.*'"
  }
}

console.log(obj.error.errors[0].message);
console.log(obj.error.message);
```

Comment: My datatype is already JSON in my ajax call, so this wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: If it is already JSON, you can skip the "JSON.parse" and: var jsonObj = xhr.responseText.

Comment: `console.log(xhr.responseText.error.errors[0].message);` gives me `Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined`

Comment: According to the jquery documentation, the responseText is just text, so I included the JSON.parse to make sure it is JSON.

Comment: Did you try the JSON.parse? How about console.log the jsonObj?

Comment: console.log(jsonObj.error.errors[0].message);
console.log(jsonObj.error.message);

Comment: These should work, you can try the snippet in my answer.

Comment: This works: `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); var message = jsonObj.error.message; console.log(message);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `jQuery.parseJSON` method.

```
var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText); 
console.log(jsonObj.message);
```